# Memcached container access across hosts

Tags: docker, docker-compose, memcached

I have two hosts HostA and HostB which currently uses memcached installed on HostA. I am containerizing memcached on HostA and the services that uses this container from HostA can connect to it by using hostname as 'memcached' and port '11211'. What is the hostname that I should use when I connect to this container from HostB? Should I use HostA's IP address and port 11211?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to use the HostA's IP Address and port 11211, as you mentioned, as long as the [port is exposed and firewall rules set appropriately](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/container-communication/#container-communication-between-hosts).

Another option is to create an [overlay network](https://docs.docker.com/network/overlay/) and keep using the name of the container (e.g. memcached). It's a bit more difficult to set up and requires an extra piece of software for service discovery (e.g. Consul, ZK, etcd). On the bright side, it also makes the whole thing more dynamic. A good reference [in this blog post](https://codeblog.dotsandbrackets.com/multi-host-docker-network-without-swarm/).